# Finding difficult in looping table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to get all `<input>`, select the name and all data-attributes which are inside the column in the table. I'm stuck, my table loop starts from 5th row instead of starting from 2nd;

```
var rowNo = jQuery(this).attr("data-row");
jQuery("#example1 table tbody").find('tr').each(function (key, value) {
    jQuery(this).find('td').each(function (key, val) {
        var tName = jQuery(this).find('input,select').attr('name');
        console.log(tName);
    });
});
```

and

```
<div id="example1">
<table id="Invoice">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="header_table">
            <th></th>
            <th>InvoiceNo</th>
            <th>InvoiceDate</th>
       </tr>
        <tr class="even" name="tr_2">
            <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o icon-class" data-row="2"></i></td>
            <td><input data-cols="1" data-row="2" name="input_[2][InvoiceNo]" type="text"></td>
            <td><input data-cols="2" data-row="2" name="input_[2][InvoiceDate]" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
         .....
         ...
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

output

```
"select_[5][Supplier]"
"input_[5][Description]"
"input_[5][Serial]"
"select_[5][AssetType]"
"select_[5][PurchasePrice]"
"input_[5][PONumber]"
```

tested my the html table

```
  jQuery("table").find('tr').each(function(key,value){
                jQuery(this).find('th,td').each(function(key1,val){
                    console.log(key1);
                });
            });
```

I get output as:

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
.
...

...

..
```

Comment: fix your html. you don't write end tag of your first **tr**.

Comment: it just typo in question i even cannot loop from column 1 the table looping start from 3

Comment: It's completely unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: i'm not able to loop through table correctly

Comment: @MayuriS, see here (https://jsfiddle.net/2296gdru/). after fix your html it works fine.

Comment: @MayuriS It's not unclear you want to *do*, it's unclear what you want to *achieve*.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMahediSabuj, closing `</tr>` tags are optional.  Your fiddle should work the same without them.

Comment: i want reterieve all td data from table but my looping start from 3rd column of 1st row so i want to fix that

Comment: @MayuriS, then show us your full html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments

> i want retrieve all td data from table

I translate that as *"I want to have a collection of all data in all input fields in my table"*.

This could look as simple as:

```
var data = {};
jQuery("#example1 table input").each(function () {
    data[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

This produces an object with keys and values for further processing.

If the `data` is directly for transmission to a server, it becomes as simple as

```
var data = jQuery("#example1 table").serialize();

$.post("url", data);
```

Comment: @MayuriS Notice the difference between what you want to do and what you want to achieve? Next time you ask a question here, try to concentrate more on the desired result you want to have in the end (and less on the activities you think you need for that).

Comment: yes sure hey once again thanks for showing example of data transmission